# Why do i never enter in specific callback functions in native interface?

Tags: codenameone

I'm making an application which has to detect a bluetooth card reader and if a card is inserted or removed from this one.

I'm using an API for the android part in my native interface so I implement two callback functions from an interface which concerns the bluetooth card reader detection and two other callback functions which concerns the detection of cards in the bluetooth card reader.

Two callback functions which are called when the bluetooth card reader is detected and the two others which are called when a card is inserted or removed from the device.

I have no problem with the callback which are called when the bluetooth card reader is detected but the application never calls the functions which must be called when the card are inserted or removed.

```
public class FtReaderNativeImpl implements BluetoothRead.CardListener,BluetoothRead.ReaderListener{

    private BluetoothRead btRead;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> listRead;

    public String scanBluetooth(){
        String chaine ="";
        if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
        { 
          Looper.prepare();
        }
        Log.p("btread avant init:"+btRead);
        btRead = new 

     BluetoothRead(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
     btRead.setCardListener(this);
     btRead.setReaderListener(this);
     ReturnCode rc = btRead.btInitLib();
     Log.p("btread après init:"+btRead);
     Log.p("rc:"+rc);
     return chaine;
    }
       @Override
       public void CardInserted()
       {
                //showMessage("onCardInserted");
                String chaine=""; 
                //Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                chaine+=btRead.getName();
                chaine+=btRead.getFirstName();
                eidReader.showDialog("INSERTED "+chaine);
                Log.p("btInsertOK");
       }

       @Override
       public void CardRemoved()
       {
                   String chaine=""; 
                   //Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "REMOVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   EidReader.showDialog("REMOVED "+chaine);
                   Log.p("btRemoveNOK");
       }

       @Override
       public void ReaderConnected(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) 
       {
           /*Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
          EidReader.showDialog("CONNECTED");
          Log.p("onReaderConnected: " + bluetoothDevice.getName());
          if (btRead.btOpen(bluetoothDevice) == ReturnCode.OK) {
             Log.p("btOpen OK");

          } else {
             Log.p("btOpen NOK");
          }
          Log.p("btread après listener:"+btRead);
       }

       @Override
       public void ReaderDisconnected(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) 
       {
          //Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           EidReader.showDialog("DISCONNECTED");
       }}
```

ScanBluetooth is just a initialization method which is called in the beginning of the form:

```
public class EidReader extends Form implements HasLogger {

Container loggatt = new Container();
    private Bluetooth bt;
    private static Container devicesCnt;
    private Map devices = new HashMap();
    Form main = this;
    FtReaderNative frn;

    public EidReader(Form parent)
    {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Display dis = Display.getInstance();
        frn = (FtReaderNative)NativeLookup.create(FtReaderNative.class);
        if(dis.getPlatformName().compareTo("and")==0){
            LocationManager lm = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
        }
        bt = new Bluetooth();
        frn.scanBluetooth();
        //combo.setRenderer(new GenericListCellRenderer<>(new MultiButton(),new MultiButton()));
        this.add(new Button(new Command("enable bluetooth")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

                try {
                    if (!bt.isEnabled()) {
                        bt.enable();
                    }
                    if (!bt.hasPermission()) {
                        bt.requestPermission();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
        this.add(new Button(new Command("initialize")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                try {
                    bt.initialize(true, false, "bluetoothleplugin");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        Button bttest = new Button("DISPLAY READER");
        bttest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                DeleteUI();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(frn.infoDevices());
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(st.nextToken());
                    mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                            devicesCnt.add(new SpanLabel(frn.readerStatus( mb.getTextLine1())));
                        }});
                    devicesCnt.add(mb);
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(bttest);
        devicesCnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        devicesCnt.setScrollableY(true);
        this.add(devicesCnt);
        this.show();
}

    private void DeleteUI()
    {
        devicesCnt.removeAll();
        devicesCnt.revalidate();
    }
    @Override
    public String getLogName() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public static void showDialog(String txt)
    {
        //Display.getInstance().callSerially(()->
        //{
            devicesCnt.add(new SpanLabel(txt));
            devicesCnt.forceRevalidate();
        //});
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly `onReaderConnected` is invoked but there is no span label on the form? Why did you comment out the call serially in `showDialog`? It should be there as you invoke the method off the EDT.

Comment: ReaderConnected is invoked when the reader is connected to the phone
ReaderDisconnected is invoked when the reader is connected to the phone
CardInserted should be invoke when card is inserted into the card reader, but it's not (in CN1)

Strange behavior, but maybe it can help somehow, if we insert the card soon enough into the reader, ReaderConnected is invoked and CardInserted is also invoked. But if there is more than a few second between those events, second event (CardInserted) will not occur.

Comment: With Android Studio, working with a simple APK, same code is working, all listeners are working.

Should we suspect something with `btRead = new BluetoothRead(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());` ?
Can the context change or evolve somehow ?

Comment: I don't think that should be. You can use include source and then debug this in Android studio as explained here https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-debug-on-an-android-device.html